# How to connect Android Studio to Network and then to MS SQL?

Tags: android

lately i've been trying to develop a app in Android Studio that it should print results in my emulador, but since i'm a beginner in this field(Java/Android) i searched a lot and i discover that the difference between my code and the others code has been that i'm trying to connect directly from my Android App to SQL, and what i really want it's to connect from Android to Network(of my company) and then connect to SQL Server, can someone help me?

Here it is the code i develop: (Android App directly to SQL Server)

public class manutencao extends Activity {

```
Button executar;
EditText buscar;
ListView listar;
Connection connect;
SimpleAdapter dataAdapt;



private void declarar()
{
    executar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Executar);
    buscar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_campo);
    listar = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

}

private void inicializar()
{
    declarar();
    buscar.setText("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Gav_Auto_Manutencao_Autonoma");
    connect = CONN("*user","*pass", "GAV_Manutencao", "*ip");

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private Connection CONN(String _user, String _passe, String _BD, String _server)
{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String connURL = null;
    try {

        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        connURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + _server + ";" + "databaseName=" + _BD + ";user=" + _user + ";password=" + _passe + ";";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);

    } catch (SQLException se) {

        Log.e("Erro", se.getMessage());

    }  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Erro", e.getMessage());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Erro", e.getMessage());
    }

    return conn;
}


public void QuerySQL(String comandoSQL){
    ResultSet rs;
    try {

        Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(comandoSQL);

        List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        while(rs.next()){
            Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
            datanum.put("A", rs.getString("Posto"));
            data.add(datanum);
        }

        String[] from = {"A"};
        int [] views = {R.id.txt_titulo, R.id.txt_conteudo};
        dataAdapt = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.modelo, from, views);
        listar.setAdapter(dataAdapt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manutencao);

    inicializar();

    executar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            QuerySQL(buscar.getText().toString());


        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An android app that can send direct sql queries to the companies database?

I think you should go the HTTP/JSON way.

http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: maybe my explanation was wrong, what i want is to list the machines that are stopped by malfunction, and i want to list that in a listbox when i open my app and this listbox will update in real time. For that i read that connecting directly from the Android Studio to SQL Server it's a bad option, so what i really want is to send the request to the network of the company and then send the request to SQL that will reply me with the info.

Comment: where is the problem? a php, python, perl script can do the sql query and send back the live data as json, this way no one can drop your database by getting the db credentials from your android app.

Comment: the problem here is that i don't see how i'm gonna do that, or the spot where i'm gonna implement it, can you help me with that giving me a example(rather PHP) thanks for the quick answer

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/